# Run application from html button using php/perl

Tags: linux, debian, php, perl

I was wondering if there is any way to open an application or file browser such as nautilus from a local html button using php or perl. The webpage is local and I have php and perl installed. I can run shell scripts that print "Hello World" to the php page, but is there anyway to open an application from the webpage? I am using Debian

Comment: Do you want the person connected to the wesbite to run the program on their computer or have the program run on the server.  There is a huge difference.

Comment: it's running on the server. The webpage will be accessed from the server, and the program needs to be launched on the server.

Comment: You understand if you open an application on the server, that the user visiting the website, will be unware the application has been opened right?  There also is nothing that prevents hundreds of instances of this application from opening, if hundreds of users, visit your website. Can you please clarify what your question is exactly?

Comment: [Execute an external program](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: (To Ramhound) Yes, This project is very odd. the html page will only be accessed by one person, the website will never be public.

Comment: (To Alex) I have tried that. I can execute the command nautilus or execute a shell script that has the line nautilus in it, and when I run it from the terminal it works, but from the browser it does not. I have used chmod to apply the correct permissions. This has led me to believe it may have something to do with the X server.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the inherent security risks and issues with permissions, it can be done, yes.  This is assuming the webserver, the web client, and the gui app are all to be run on the SAME box.

Here is an example CGI script that will launch a local X app:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("export DISPLAY=:0.0;/usr/bin/nedit");
```

The process (in this case, nedit) will be run as the webserver user (in the case of my CentOS box, apache).  Check the apache error log for the various errors and warnings you will encounter.

You may (likely) need to fiddle with X server settings in order to get things to work.